# Why is a value appended to the list in the loop although there is a condition which leads to "break"?

Tags: python, loops

Why is there 1.0 in the output if my `if` statement is `y > 0.9999`?

If I put `>=` it does not help.

```
from math import sin, pi

X = []
Y = []
x = 0
y = 0

while True:
    x += 1
    X.append(x)
    y = sin(x * pi / 180)
    Y.append(y)
    if y > 0.9999:
        print(f"breaking on y = {y}")
        break

    print(f"sin {x} degree = {y}")

print(f"List X = {X}")
print(f"List Y = {Y}")
```

Output:

```
sin 1 degree = 0.01745240643728351
sin 2 degree = 0.03489949670250097
...
sin 89 degree = 0.9993908270190958
sin 90 degree = 0.9998476951563913
breaking on y = 1.0
List X = [0, 1, 2,... 89, 90]
List Y = [0.01745240643728351, 0.03489949670250097,... 0.9998476951563913, 1.0]
```

Comment: Because you append it to the list before the `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you break **after** checking your condition, at this point `y` is already added to your output list.

Move instead the `Y.append(y)` **after** the test/break (and `X.append(x)` if you want both lists to have the same number of items):

```
X = []
Y = []
x = 0
y = 0

while True:
    x += 1
    y = sin(x * pi / 180)
    if y > 0.9999:
        print(f"breaking on y = {y}")
        break
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    print(f"sin {x} degree = {y}")
```

Last item of `Y`: `0.9998476951563913`

Answer (score 0):

`break` does not mean that the *entire* body of the loop is skipped or undone for this iteration.

Statements are executed sequentially from top to bottom and only the part *after* the `break` statement is skipped. The statements that have already been executed (like appending `y` to `Y`) are still in effect.